# Can I make this assertion generic in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to make an assertion that the type returned by a function in someone else's crate is big enough, and don't feel like changing my code if they change theirs to something that's still ok.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do ([playground](http://is.gd/t27l0K)):

```
const NANOSECONDS_IN_DAY:f64 = 8.64E13;
trait HasMax<T> {
    fn max_value() -> T;
}
fn max_of<T:HasMax>(_: &T) -> T {
    T::max_value()
}
fn main() {
    let mv = max_of(&1f64);
    assert!(mv > NANOSECONDS_IN_DAY, "type is too small");
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
<anon>:5:13: 5:19 error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0 [E0243]
<anon>:5 fn max_of<T:HasMax>(_: &T) -> T {
                     ^~~~~~
```

Comment: If we pretend that the other crate switches to a `u64`  from a `f64`, even if the example code compiled, it would try to compare a `u64` to a `f64`, which doesn't work. Beyond that, presumably the other crate doesn't know about `HasMax`, so the local crate would have to implement it for various types, which means the local code would have to add a new implementation if the type changed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something about traits, the other crate returns a i64 right now, (I forgot to cast in my example code to deal with `>` not working) and i64 (and other primitive numeric types) implement `::max_value`. So I thought this should work.

Comment: *primitive numeric types implement `max_value`* — what would you like to  happen when the API changes to return a `struct Time(u64, u64)`?

Comment: Then it wouldn't compile, but while it still remains a primitive numeric type and said types continue to implement max_value it'd be nice to set and forget. It gets me some extra longevity even if it's not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern crate num;
extern crate time;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use num::Bounded;
    use time::{self,Tm};
    #[test]
    fn size_test() {
        let NANOSECONDS_IN_DAY:f64 = 8.64E13;
        fn max_of<T:Bounded>(_: T) -> T {
            T::max_value()
        }
        let type_v = time::Duration::zero().num_nanoseconds().unwrap();
        let mv = max_of(type_v);
        assert!(mv as f64 > NANOSECONDS_IN_DAY, "type is too small");
    }
}
```

This works.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to make your code work in spite of unknown future breaking API changes in a library you are using is misguided at best.  The short answer is that if the API of a library you are using changes, it is better that your code will fail to compile instead of failing in some more subtle or difficult to detect way.  But I can answer why your code isn't compiling.

The problem is in your trait definition, which uses generics.  Your trait should be `HasMax`, not `HasMax<T>`.

```
const NANOSECONDS_IN_DAY:f64 = 8.64E13;
trait HasMax {
    fn max_value() -> Self;
}
fn max_of<T:HasMax>(_: &T) -> T {
    T::max_value()
}
impl HasMax for f64 {
    fn max_value() -> Self {
        std::f64::MAX
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mv = max_of(&1f64);
    assert!(mv > NANOSECONDS_IN_DAY, "type is too small");
}
```

Comment: In addition, I'd point out that you don't really need the `max_of` function as it just requires you to create a value that appears to be unused for anything else. Instead, you could just call `let mv = <f64 as HasMax>::max_value()`. See also [`size_of`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) and [`size_of_val`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html) for a parallel concept.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  The whole thing is a little overdesigned.

Comment: That suggests another approach, `assert!(std::mem::size_of_val(api::function()) < 6, "type is too small");`

Comment: @CamdenNarzt: That doesn't do what we want, because we want to know the range of values, not the amount of storage used to represent the values.

Comment: the range is to my knowledge at least 2^(bytes*8-1)

Comment: @CamdenNarzt: That's not true.  The result could be a fixed-point number.

Comment: Fair enough, rust or a crate could add those at some point. Is there a way to automatically add a trait to all primitive types that already implement the max_value fn?

Comment: @CamdenNarzt: I don't think so, since `max_value()` isn't attached to any trait.